# How to use GetElementsByTagName on a Tag That Is Insıde a Spesific Tag XMLDocument C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I need to read an Xml file and I am trying to count the numbers of a spesific tag inside the file. My problem is the same tag represents different things when it is outside some other tag and inside. I am able to get total count of the tag but I need to find the count of the tag that is inside the specified tag.

(I find total cac:AllowanceCharge tags by using XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("cac:AllowanceCharge");)

To Find the "cac:AllowanceCharge" tags that are inside the "cac:InvoiceLine" tags i have tried using:

```
XmlNodeList elemList = root.GetElementsByTagName(@"//cac:InvoiceLine/cac:AllowanceCharge");

XmlNodeList elemList = root.GetElementsByTagName(@"//InvoiceLine/AllowanceCharge");

XmlNodeList elemList = root.GetElementsByTagName(@"cac:InvoiceLine/cac:AllowanceCharge");
```

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me the right syntax for it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first looks correct, if you registered namespace binding `cac`

```
//cac:InvoiceLine/cac:AllowanceCharge
```

There is also another way

```
//*[name()='InvoiceLine']/*[name()='AllowanceCharge']
```

To select the nodes by XPath, call the `SelectNodes` method:

```
var root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
var nodeList = root.SelectNodes(xpath);
```

or the overloaded method

```
var nodeList2 = root.SelectNodes(xpath, namespaceManager);
```

Comment: Another question, how can I look for a spesific attribute? I am using "//*[name()='InvoiceLine']/*[name()='AllowanceCharge']"

Comment: Some examples are here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: Sorry to bother again but I have tried them but just can't get it right.